# Disable the autoplay dialog in W7

Tags: windows-7, windows, autoplay

I know that W7 has disabled the autorun feature by default when you insert a EHD if a Autorun.inf in the root folder, but plugging in the drive still caused the AutoPlay dialog to appear, Pictures and General options were listed in the dialog. I don't want to disable it from Control Panel, is there a way to write a simple file(like autorun.inf) in the root folder to disable showing the AutoPlay feature for the EHD? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, at least not with an autorun file.

Windows 7 disables the autorun.inf functionality, but AutoPlay will continue to operate as normal unless you disable it or choose "Always do this" when plugging it in.